# Erlang ssh module not recognizing my ssh keys

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm trying to connect to a sever using ssh keys, but I keep getting asked for a password. I've tried with and without the user_dir option. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
:ssh.start
{:ok, S} = :ssh.connect('some.host.com', 22,
                        [
                         {:silently_accept_hosts, true},
                         {:user_dir, '/Users/nan/.ssh'}
                       ])
#...
:ssh.close(S)
:ssh.stop
```

Comment: Can you connect to the host with bare ssh client without entering your password?

Comment: Yup, there's no problem doing it normally. eg. ssh user@some.host.com

Comment: Did you try to pass `user` option?

Comment: Yes I did, and it still does not work. Everything works great if I use  password authentication. It's just the ssh keys that are not working.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Comment: I had same problem after debugging found out that I have passphrase on my key :D
If this the same for you, you should provide the passphrase as `rsa_pass_phrase` option

Answer (score 2):

Check the content of your ~/.ssh/config file. I believe that Erlang module is looking for id_rsa or id_dsa files directly in the directory. You might have an entry in your config file for some.host.com which defaults to different key location or different user name. Because of this, logging using command line works and it fails when the module tries to establish connection.

Also check what keys you have currently loaded in your agent session (ssh-add -L). Perhaps your are using a different key for this particular host than you suspect.